# Having trouble converting this Jade to EJS

Tags: node.js, express, pug, ejs

I am attempting to utilize the [JShare](https://github.com/brooklynDev/JShare) module for Node/Express.

The example given on Github says:

> Next, you need to make a call out to the JShare helper method in your layout file:

```
!!!
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    !{includeJShare()}
  body!= body
```

So, this example is in Jade. I am using EJS, and for the life of me, I can't figure out how to implement the helper method... This seems so simple, but I'm not sure what **!{}** does in Jade, or how to replicate it in EJS.

Comment: what does `includeJShare()` do? because in ejs you can just do `<% include filename %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!{var}` is unescaped interpolation in jade. You should be able to get the same thing in ejs by doing:

```
<%- includeJShare() %>
```

This should write in a `<script>` tag.

**Edit**

If ejs tries to parse `include`, submit a patch request to https://github.com/brooklynDev/JShare/issues (or to ejs) and in the meantime go into node_modules/JShare/jshare.js and change `res.locals.includeJShare` to just `res.locals.JShare` and then use `JShare()` in your ejs.

Comment: That was my guess, but it's returning: 
`Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\...\htdocs\www\_oodle\views\JShare().ejs'`

I think it's trying to parse it with the "include" keyword... Like @chovy points out, it's a keyword, but all I'm trying to run is the actual function named "includeJShare".

Comment: Ah yes. That error would have been good to post! For now, go into node_modules/JShare/jshare.js and change includeJShare to just JShare and then use JShare() in your ejs. Then submit an issue here: https://github.com/brooklynDev/JShare/issues

Comment: Thank you! Works swell. It has to go in as `<%- JShare() %>` so that it doesn't escape the html tags around `script`.

Comment: Thanks again, @glortho, and I put up an issue on Github like you suggested.

Comment: @minttoothpick I wrote JShare and I thank you for bringing this to my attention. I just posted an update to fix this issue. You can now call either JShare() or includeJShare() (from Jade) within your view. The NPM version has also been updated.

Comment: Thanks @BFree! JShare's been a really helpful module!